# how to create multiple owners : Solidity

Tags: solidity, ethereum-classic

I am creating a contract in which i want is like multiple owners have the rights to whitelist the user.

```
contract Whitelist {

    mapping(address => bool) Users;
    address private owner;
    address private otherOwner;

    function Whitelist() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
//Modifier for owner access
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
            _;
    }
//Function to add users
    function userAdd(address userAddress) onlyOwner {
            require(userAddress != 0x0 && !Users[userAddress]);             
            Users[userAddress] = true;    

    }
//Checking the user is whitelist
    function isWhitelisted(address passAddress) external returns (bool) {   
        return Users[passAddress];
    }
```

i am not getting idea about how to do that.
need help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RBAC.sol contract from OpenZeppelin https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/rbac/RBAC.sol.

It has `onlyAdmin` and `onlyRole` modifiers. Multiple users holding different roles can be added. You can have arbitrary roles e.g. WHITELISTED.

Alternatively you can use `Whitelist.sol` contract https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/pull/746/files#diff-8d5f210f8ce2e6f8d7f62f655e6f72ec

Comment: the first URL is broken.

Comment: Looks like they refactored it and move some of the code here https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/access

Answer (score 2):

this is a sample of multiple owner smart contract, you can extend your contract from this contract to have the multiple owner

```
contract MultiOwnable {
    address public manager; // address used to set owners
    address[] public owners;
    mapping(address => bool) public ownerByAddress;

    event SetOwners(address[] owners);

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(ownerByAddress[msg.sender] == true);
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev MultiOwnable constructor sets the manager
     */
    function MultiOwnable() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Function to set owners addresses
     */
    function setOwners(address[] _owners) public {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _setOwners(_owners);

    }

    function _setOwners(address[] _owners) internal {
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < owners.length; i++) {
            ownerByAddress[owners[i]] = false;
        }


        for(uint256 j = 0; j < _owners.length; j++) {
            ownerByAddress[_owners[j]] = true;
        }
        owners = _owners;
        emit SetOwners(_owners);
    }

    function getOwners() public constant returns (address[]) {
        return owners;
    }
}

contract Pausable is MultiOwnable {

    uint public endDate;

    /**
    * @dev modifier to allow actions only when the contract IS not paused
    */
    modifier whenNotPaused() {
        require(now >= endDate);
        _;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already use mapping to identify users that have been whitelisted. Why not also use a Map to store the admins?

```
contract Whitelist {
 mapping(address => uint) whitelist;
 mapping(address => uint) admins;

    function Whitelist() {
        admins[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    modifier onlyAdmin() {
        require(admin[msg.sender] == true);
            _;
    }


    function addWhitelist(address userAddress) onlyAdmin {
            require(userAddress != 0x0 && !whitelist[userAddress]);             
            whitelist[whitelist] = true;    
    }

    function isWhitelisted(address passAddress) external returns (bool) {   
        return whitelist[passAddress];
    }

    function addAdmin(address userAddress) onlyAdmin {
            require(userAddress != 0x0 && !admins[userAddress]);             
            admins[userAddress] = true;    

    }
}
```

You can also create different permission tiers, where there is only one owner who can add admins who can add whitelisted.

Comment: lot's of typos and debug error in remix editor :s

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've set `otherOwner`, just change your modifier thusly:

```
require(owner == msg.sender || otherOwner == msg.sender);
```